# ionic device plugin returning null

Tags: ionic4, ionic-native

No matter what I do or try I can't get info about the device.  I'm using last version of ionic 4.

Since  all I find online is basically

- Don't execute on browser
- get the values one by one

Of course that's not what's going on. I'm not doing that, I have cordova available, etc.

I'm testing on device, both android and ios. I deal with this in a service. I'm calling the functions with buttons so everything is more than loeaded, everything is ready. This is the code I'm trying to make work:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InitialService {

  eldevice: any = '';

  constructor(
    private device: Device,
    private platform: Platform
  ) {}

  async setup() {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) { // es movil

      this.eldevice = await this.storage.get('device');

      if (this.eldevice == null) { // nuevo device

        this.eldevice.platform = this.device.platform;
        this.eldevice.version = this.device.version;
        this.eldevice.uuid = this.device.uuid;
        this.eldevice.manufacturer = this.device.manufacturer;

        console.log('datos sin await', this.eldevice);

        this.eldevice = await this.storage.set('device', this.device);

      } else { // device conocido
        console.log('datos guardados', this.eldevice);

      }
    } else { // es virtual
      console.log('virtual');

    }
  }

  clearData() {
    this.storage.clear();
    this.eldevice = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

Any cordova plugins require you to await for platform to be in "ready" state.
So before calling / using plugins you need to call platform.ready() method and call specific plugin functions in the callback, or after "await".

Also looking at your setup() method you seem like attempting to access properties of an object that gets 'null' assigned to it after storage check. See comments in the code below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InitialService {

  eldevice: any = '';

  constructor(
    private device: Device,
    private platform: Platform
  ) {}

  async setup() {

    // await for platform ready:
    await this.platform.ready();

    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) { // es movil

      this.eldevice = await this.storage.get('device');

      if (this.eldevice == null) { // nuevo device

        // here below 'eldevice' is null (as confirmed by the check above) and you are attempting to assign something to non existing properties (platform, version etc).
        // to fix you need actual object to be assigned to eldevice:
        this.eldevice = {
            platform: this.device.platform,
            version: this.device.version,
            uuid: this.device.uuid,
            manufacturer: this.device.manufacturer
        }
        //this.eldevice.platform = this.device.platform;
        //this.eldevice.version = this.device.version;
        //this.eldevice.uuid = this.device.uuid;
        //this.eldevice.manufacturer = this.device.manufacturer;

        console.log('datos sin await', this.eldevice);

        this.eldevice = await this.storage.set('device', this.device);

      } else { // device conocido
        console.log('datos guardados', this.eldevice);

      }
    } else { // es virtual
      console.log('virtual');

    }
  }

  clearData() {
    this.storage.clear();
    this.eldevice = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, same. null is not an object (evaluating 'this.eldevice.platform = this.device.platform') I'm not sure what's going on. It's called with a button so platform had more than enough time, and now with that await... I don't understand what could be going wrong.

Comment: @monxas plz check, I think I missed something in your setup  method;)